# How do I pass back additional context variable in this Django class-based-view?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django class-based-view for form-submission called myView as shown below.
This view takes arguments submitted as part of the URL as well as data that the user fills into form fields. When the form submission is valid, everything works perfectly.

However, in the case that the form fields fail validation, then I want those errors to show up on the page and the user has to re-submit. The added wrinkle is that two extra arguments (myArg1 and myArg2) need to be sent as part of the context dictionary when this happens.

Currently, form_invalid returns `super(myView, self).form_invalid(form)`. How do I add myArg1 and myArg2 to this return statement such that they are in the new re-submitted context?

```
class myView(FormView, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'myTemplate.html'
    form_class = myForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("mySuccess")


    def form_valid(self, form):
        BlahBlahBlah


    def form_invalid(self, form):

        myArg1 = "A"
        myArg2 = "B"


        return super(myView, self).form_invalid(form) 
        # I need to send back myArg1 and myArg2 as members of the 
        # context dictionary in the line above. How?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed you code to follow a bit the python guidelines (regarding naming classes etc), what you need is in the form_invalid method.
Please don't use `FormView` and `TemplateView` together, there is no need...`FormView` is enough:

```
class MyView(FormView):
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    form_class = MyForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("my-success")


    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form,myArg1='A',myArg2='B'))
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for two reasons: 1) If I remove the subclassing of TemplateView, then in form_invalid(), get_context_date() and form_valid(), kwargs no longer contains the arguments I'm passing in on the URL. I need those 2) I tried your suggested solution for render_to_response. That causes the form to re-appear empty -- without the data the user filled and without any of the form error messages.

Comment: FormView extends View (and some other classes) the same as TemplateView, all of the above functions exist in FormView, If you don't understand CBV's how they work and how they inherit then this link will help you:
http://ccbv.co.uk/